# 2000 Suzuki 1500 Intruder problems switching to N

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, gears

I have a 2000 1500 Intruder and lately I have had big problems getting it into neutral. The bad part is that this is a big bike and hard for me to rock it back and forth to get it in N.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you state exactly what your question is here?

Comment: What specifically is the problem getting into neutral? Does the lever go right past it, or is it physically hard to shift in the direction of neutral?

Comment: Are you talking about when it is running or not? Maybe the clutch isn't disengaging completely. When was the last time the clutch was adjusted?

Answer (score 1):

If the oil hasn't been done recently, I'd start with that. Most motorcycles share oil between the engine and transmission, and you'd be surprised what a difference fresh oil can make in regards to ease of shifting.